# How to get data from previous day

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get data from the previous day, but my SQL Statements doesn't work.
I get an error:

> ORA-00904: "DATEDIFF": invalid identifier

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE DATEDIFF(day,table_name .creation_dt ,GETDATE()) = 1;

SELECT *
FROM table_name 
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(DAY, -1 , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), creation_dt) = 0;

SELECT *
FROM table_name 
WHERE `date` = creation_dt.CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

thanks Khati

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get data from the previous day,

In Oracle, I would recommend:

```
where table_name.creation_dt >= trunc(sysdate) - interval '1' day and
      table_name.creation_dt < trunc(sysdate)
```

This can make use of an index on `creation_dt`.  I also recommend that you use the `interval` syntax for working with dates.  Although you can use `trunc(sysdate) - 1`, that looks old-fashioned to me (Oracle did not always support `interval`).

You can also phrase this more concisely as:

```
where trunc(table_name.creation_dt) = trunc(sysdate) - interval '1' day
```

However, that might be a little bit more challenging for the optimizer.

Answer (score 2):

For oracle previous day you could get using *sysdate - 1*

```
select * from table_name where trunc(date) = trunc(sysdate)-1
```

Answer (score 1):

As `DATE` datatype in Oracle contains both date and time, and as "previous day" starts at `00:00:00` hours (:min:sec), then truncating `SYSDATE` "resets" time to mentioned `00:00:00`, while subtracting `1` day moves you to midnight at start of yesterday's day.

```
SQL> select trunc(sysdate) - 1 from dual;

TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1
-------------------
18.06.2020 00:00:00
```

So:

```
select *
from your_table
where date_column >= trunc(sysdate) - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

DATEDIFF is SQL Server specific function. Do you use SQL Server or another Database Engine?

Comment: This should be a comment.